# Getting character by its position instead of list values

Tags: python, list

I a have list like the one below:

```
['LDf12yiH3xpt4dtepYyqdw==', '802970-0', 'LIFETIME RENTS', 'LIFE ASSURANCE']
```

And I'm trying to get its values to assign them to other variables. However, when use `for` to loop it, I get the the char of each value according to given position.
For example, if I want to get the first element:

```py
reg_0 = ['LDf12yiH3xpt4dtepYyqdw==', '802970-0', 'LIFETIME RENTS', 'LIFE ASSURANCE']
for i in reg_0:
        print(i[0])

expected_output = 'LDf12yiH3xpt4dtepYyqdw=='
current_output = 'L 8 L L' # one char of each value, each line
```

Comment: @HenryEcker i would say the first one, not only access/get/print them but use them in future. However I got the anwser before I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to print just the first item.

```
print(reg_0[0])
```

Here is the solution to print each item.

```
for i in reg_0:
    print(i)
```

Comment: I had already tried the second one but the thing is I need to not only get them but assign them to other variables. However, the first one is more or less what I need.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the first element of each element of the list.

```
For i in reg_0: # is calling 'LDf12yiH3xpt4dtepYyqdw==' as i
    and i[0] # is calling 'L'
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

`for` iterates over each element in the list. In your example, `i` will be the element in `reg_0`. If you want to iterate by index, you could do:

```
for i in range(0, len(reg_0)):
    print(reg_0[i])
```

Or you could simply access the elements directly

```
for i in reg_0:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `for i in range(0, len(reg_0)):` that's super ugly. You'd rather remove this option from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is:

```
for i in reg_0:
```

Here, you are iterating over the elements of the list. `print(i[0])` is printing the first letter of the element because `i` is assigned an element from the list when it iterates and you are indexing the first element of `i`. So, here is some sample:

```
for i in reg_0:
    print(i[0])
```

It is doing the following:

```
i='LDf12yiH3xpt4dtepYyqdw=='
i[0]='L' # printed

i='802970-0' 
i[0]='8' # printed

i='LIFETIME RENTS'
i[0]='L' # printed

i='LIFE ASSURANCE'
i[0]='L' # printed
```

If you simply want the first element of the list, then do `reg_0[0]`

```
reg_0 = ['LDf12yiH3xpt4dtepYyqdw==', '802970-0', 'LIFETIME RENTS', 'LIFE ASSURANCE']
print(reg_0[0])
```